# Hide fixed header on scroll down, show on scroll up and hover

Tags: jquery, header

I have a fixed header that hides on scroll down and shows again on scroll up, this all works as intended. But I'd also like it to show up when you hover it's position, any ideas?

What I got so far:

```
$(function(){
var lastScrollTop = 0, delta = 5;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();

   if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
      return;

   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       // downscroll code
       $("#header").css('visibility','hidden').hover ()
   } else {
      // upscroll code
      $("#header").css('visibility','visible');
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r6kTs/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try change its top position instead:

```
if (st > lastScrollTop){
       // downscroll code
       $("#header").css({top:'-120px'})
       .hover(function(){$("#header").css({top: '0px'})})
   } else {
      // upscroll code
      $("#header").css({top:'0px'});
   }
```

And add this to #header css:

```
#header{
    /*YOUR CSS*/
    border-bottom: 2px solid #333 ;
    }
```

That way you can hover over the header's bottom border and show it.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Good idea, works as intended! I increased the border size a bit to make it easier to activate and made the border transparent.

http://jsfiddle.net/uAc3p/5/

Thanks

Comment: @oscarpas your jsfiddle is a better standalone solution, then about 20 github big libraries I've seen!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following using the `clientY` property of event object to check the position of mouse relative to viewport.

```
$(document).on('mousemove',function(e){
    var hidden = ($("#header").css('visibility')!='visible');
    console.log(hidden);
    if(e.clientY <70 && hidden)
        $("#header").css('visibility','visible');
    else if(e.clientY >70 && !hidden)
        $("#header").css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

Not sure if this is the best way (*tested in latest versions of major browsers but not the oldest ones*)

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6kTs/1/)