# Jquery nav bar hider script using lot of resources and generating console errors on Jquery 3 beta

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-3

I have this navbar hider script for handheld devices:

```
function bindNavUp() {
  var lastScrollTop = 0, delta = 5;
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta) {
      return;
    };

    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
      // downscroll code
      $('header.main').css('top','-50px').hover();
    }
    else {
      // upscroll code
      $('header.main').css('top','0');
    };
    lastScrollTop = st;
  });
};
function unbindNavUp() {
  $(window).unbind('scroll');
};
function handleNavUp() {
  if ($(window).width() < 1600) {
    bindNavUp();
  }
  else {
    unbindNavUp(); 
  };
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timer;
  $(window).on('load resize scroll', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      handleNavUp();  
    }, 100);
  });
  handleNavUp();
});
```

The problem with this is that upscrolling works great with Jquery 2.2.1:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lanti/03kw42o1/4/

But not with Jquery 3 Beta 1, the hidden elements of the header not coming back (I use Firefox latest):

https://jsfiddle.net/Lanti/03kw42o1/5/

Also, with Jquery 3 I've got lots of console errors: `TypeError: c is null`

I haven't got any of this with Jquery 2.2.1, but both cases I also feel a huge performance drop when this script is applied to the normal, non-responsive view of my design.

Comment: What are you expecting `$('header.main').css('top','-50px').hover();` to do??? Specifaclly speaking about calling `hover()`???

Comment: I found that part of the script here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765185/hide-fixed-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-and-hover

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot (no more) pass undefined as event handler, now jQuery throws error. `hover()` is a shorthand for mouseenter/mouseleave events, just remove `.hover()` (which i still don't see any purpose for it), what do you get? Expected result?

Comment: Yes! Thank You, it's fixing it. Console errors are gone and working with Jquery 3. I watched the linked Stackoverflow question, and possible reason of hover is that the he wanted to implement to show the header when someone hover on the mouse. But this is totally un-needed for handheld devices, so I remove it.

Comment: I just checked and it seems this behaviour to throw error on undefined handler was on alpha/beta versions. Now if you use the lastest prerelease, this no more throws error. This should be related: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/fac67a984268ef8f7de952666fda6d8d32754f5f   Updated jsFiddle using lastest jq3 pre release https://jsfiddle.net/03kw42o1/7/

Comment: This is related indeed: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2851 **&&** https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2812

Comment: Now my code looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lanti/03kw42o1/9/ I removed the `.hover()` event because I only use this for handheld devices. Also, `$(window).unbind('scroll');` is a good way to remove the code where I not want to run?

Comment: However this responsive view also applies for desktop, so maybe it's a good thing to have hover there: https://jsfiddle.net/Lanti/03kw42o1/10/