# How to reveal a React component on scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I've created a React component for a fixed nav that I would like to remain hidden, until I scroll past a certain point on the page, then slides into view. [Medium](https://medium.com/migration-issues/westeros-is-poorly-designed-3b01cf5cdcaf) has a header similar to what I'm describing.

This is a relatively trivial task in [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765185/hide-fixed-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-and-hover), with scrollmagic or waypoints but is there an idiomatic way of accomplishing this with React and vanilla JS?

Answer (score 20):

React Way with vanilla JS [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/260640/);

don't forget to remove EventListener. In this example component will render if only it is neccessary

```
class TopBar extends React.Component {
    state = { isHide: false };

    hideBar = () => {
       const { isHide } = this.state

       window.scrollY > this.prev ?
       !isHide && this.setState({ isHide: true })
       :
       isHide && this.setState({ isHide: false });

       this.prev = window.scrollY;
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.hideBar);
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
         window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.hideBar);
    }

    render(){
        const classHide = this.state.isHide ? 'hide' : '';
        return <div className={`topbar ${classHide}`}>topbar</div>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You could use a component such as [react-headroom](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/react-headroom) to do the heavy lifting for you. Or, you can still use waypoints in React, setting it up in the `componentDidMount` [lifecycle method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods) and removing it using `componentWillUnmount`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook, do the same thing as in the jQuery link you have given:

```
class Navbar extends React.component {

  let delta = 5;

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref=header></div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
      var st = $(this).scrollTop();

      if(Math.abs(this.state.lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

      if (st > lastScrollTop){
        // downscroll code
        // $(this.refs.header).css('visibility','hidden').hover ()
        this.setState({
          navbarVisible: false
        });
      } else {
        // upscroll code
        $(this.refs.header).css('visibility','visible');
        this.setState({
          navbarVisible: true
        });
      }
      lastScrollTop = st;
    }.bind(this));

  }
}
```

Comment: I see you are very keen on helping others with React, but could you please take some time to format each answer? It's not a race or a quantity game, it's about quality. Formatting code snippets properly and checking punctuation isn't that hard :)

Comment: Ok sir Will take care of it, This is the are i am trying to improve ,I know it

Comment: This is a great answer but unfortunately, I'm not using jQuery on this project and was looking for a way of accomplishing this with just React and vanilla JS.

Comment: then u just have to attach scroll to windows window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){//do stuff})

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using jQuery inside React components

Answer (score 0):

I created a react component for this same exact need as I could not find any other implementations that matched what I needed. Even `react-headroom` did not give you something that would just scroll in after reaching a certain point on the page.

The gist is here: https://gist.github.com/brthornbury/27531e4616b68131e512fc622a61baba

I don't see any reason to copy the component code here. The code is largely based off of the `react-headroom` code but does less and is therefore simpler.

The component is the first piece of code, you could simply copy/paste then import it. After importing your code with the navbar would look something like this:

```
class MyScrollInNavBar extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <ScrollInNav scrollInHeight={150}>
          <MyNavBar />
        </ScrollInNav>
      );
    }
}
```