# Only want element to render when user scrolls to that section

Tags: reactjs

I have this animated graph on my website that you have to scroll a bit down to get to. The animation always happens immediately meaning that no one can see it actually being made since they haven't scrolled down yet. I was wondering if there is any way to make it so that that element only appears when the user scrolls to that portion of the screen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reveal a React component on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114715/how-to-reveal-a-react-component-on-scroll)

Answer (score 1):

```
npm i react-bottom-scroll-listener
```

please refer https://github.com/karl-run/react-bottom-scroll-listener#readme this gives you a listener where you can set a condition and enable it